# Find a xpath ignoring the numbers inside the string

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, xpath

The actual xpath is `//*[@id="location_in_196548881_chzn"]` and the number in between is randomly generated. I want to search this node.

My call to search is like this when the id is constant

```
find(:xpath,'//*[@id="location_in_196548881"]')
```

Tried this but didn't work

```
//id[contains(text(), 'location_in_')]
```

How could I ignore this number in between while finding this id?

The HTML snippet is

```
<div class='control-group'>
<label class='control-label' for='inputLocation'>
Location
</label>
<div class='controls location'>
<select class="span6 first" data-chosen_select="true" data-placeholder="via Location" id="location_in_196548881" name="browse[relation][location_in][]"><option value=""></option>
<optgroup label="Top"><option value="43705">Bangalore</option>
<option value="43767">Chennai</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking along the right lines, but if your original XPath is working for static numbers then just replace the `@id=''` part with what you were trying in your second XPath like so:

```
//*[contains(@id,'location_in_')]
```

If `id` is an attribute, you're referencing it correctly with the first XPath, which is why you get something back. In your second call, you're referencing it as if it's a node that contains text you're looking for.

In other words, `//id[contains(text(), 'location_in_')]` would work for something like

```
<root>
<id>location_in_12345</id>
</root>
```

But what you actually seem to be looking for is

```
<root>
<node1 id="location_in_1235">text</node1>
<node2 id="location_in_5678">text</node2>
</root>
```

So you would replace your original XPath with what I provided:

```
find(:xpath,'//*[contains(@id,"location_in_")]')
```

Comment: Provided this find(:xpath,'//*[contains(@id,"location_in_")]')
but got the result as - unable to find xpath "//*[contains(@id,\"location_in_\")]"

Comment: Could you post the XML snippet you're targeting?

Comment: </div>
<div class='control-group'>
<label class='control-label' for='inputLocation'>
Location
</label>
<div class='controls location'>
<select class="span6 first" data-chosen_select="true" data-placeholder="via Location" id="location_in_196548881" name="browse[relation][location_in][]"><option value=""></option>
<optgroup label="Top"><option value="43705">Bangalore</option>
<option value="43767">Chennai</option>

Comment: I am new to Stack over flow and don't know to generate the xml snippet out of this. So sorry for the unformatted output.

Comment: Put the XML in your original question so it can be formatted;)

Comment: Actually mistakenly I wrote node, its the normal element and want to find by id.

Comment: @JWiley Can you give me the full call similar to this find(:xpath,'//*[@id="location_in_196548881"]')
So that I can put it directly on console and test it.

Comment: The xpath I provided finds the element/node by that ID. I tried it out on a small snippet containing the line you're targeting in yours, and it returned the node you're trying to find.

Comment: @BijuVidyadharan sure, I added it to the answer